# Can I put all my libraries into one jar file using build.xml

Tags: java, ant, jar, build.xml

I am trying to find a way to put all my libraries and natives for Slick2D into one jar so I don't have to bring the lib and natives folder with my executable jar when I move it.

My project\dist folder currently contains lib, natives, and MyApp.jar.  I want to have lib and natives inside MyApp.jar and still be accessible by the program.

Here is my source code for loading the natives (It works fine, it's just for clarification on what I'm trying to do).

```
try {
    System.setProperty( "java.library.path", "natives");
        Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
        fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        System.err.println("ERROR");
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions and help.

Comment: Generally yes, but be very careful.  If two Jars have a common resource, you will run into problems.

Comment: Do you know of any examples?

Comment: Plugin frameworks that dynamically load content from a fix path using `getResource`.  Dynamic libraries which load implementations from configuration embedded within the Jars....